# wp_query show all values

Tags: wp-query, search

I have a search form with 3 fields:
city porperty type and rooms all fields are select type inputs.

If I select values for each of the fields I get the correct result.

for example:

```
city= Los Angeles
property type = apartment
room = 3
```

but if choose only city and property type and dont choose a value for rooms (lets say that the empty value is `all`). I dont get any result. I would expect to get all apartmnetns in L.A.

this is my wp query I got so far.

```
if (isset($_GET['front-side-prop-search'])){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'post_type'     => 'property',
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
            'relation '     => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_city',
                'value' => $city,
                'compare'       => '=',
                    'meta_query'    =>  array(
                    'relation '  => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key'       => 'prop_city',
                            'value'     => 'All',
                            'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_type',
                'value' => $type,
                'compare'       => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_rooms',
                'value' => $rooms,
                'compare'       => '='
            ),

        ),
    );
};
```

I am sure that my wp_query is wrong, please help me or point me to an article that could help me solve this issue.

**

### Update - What I finaly did:

**

I checked every variable as tony suggested, than I changed the `compare` sign on each query depending the variable result.

Knowing that `compare => '='` returns all the values that are equal to the value.   `compare => '!='` will return everything that is not equal to the value.

this is the code i eventually used:

```
$city = $_GET['field_59ae96d970a06'];  //prop_city
$type = $_GET['field_59ec7533be002'];  //prop_type
$rooms = $_GET['field_59ae9e2370a0b'];


//check for each var if returns empty value or not

if($city == ""){
    $city_val = "!=";
}else{
    $city_val = "=";
};

if($type == "all types"){
    $type_val = "!=";
}else{
    $type_val = "=";
};

if($rooms == "all rooms"){
    $rooms_val = "!=";
}else{
    $rooms_val = "=";
};


//the query:

if (isset($_GET['front-side-prop-search'])){

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'post_type'     => 'property',
        'meta_query'    =>  array(
            'relation '     => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_city',
                'value' => $city,
                'compare'       => $city_val,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_type',
                'value' => $type,
                'compare'       => $type_val,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'prop_rooms',
                'value' => $rooms,
                'compare'       => $rooms_val,
            ),

        ),
    );
};
```

Comment: so you say I need to avoid usin an array?

Comment: (Edited) - just wanted to point out how those logical operators can provide different results. In your case, I'd check the values before creating args. That way, if only `$city` and `$type` are selected, your query `args` only include those 2. codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thank you, if a value is not selected it returns the value 'all' . I think I just dont understand how it works. In my logic I do this: get the value $city, if value is all  retreive all data that is not the selected value. Can you please point mo to an example similar to mine?

Comment: With the `meta_query`, I don't think `value` accepts the value `all`. Codex says: value (string|array). You must supply some string for the value parameter. An empty string or NULL will NOT work. So while supplying "all" will get results, it won't get desired/accurate results. I still think it is easier to check your values before creating the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below just changes what `args` is based on your 3 input fields. This eliminates the need to check for these values (and using "all" for `value`). I'm sure some combination of logical operators for `compare` and `relation` would do the job but this works too.

```
if (isset($_GET['front-side-prop-search'])){

 // test whether $city has a selected value, if so then args below: 

 // $city and $type selected

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type'     => 'property',
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
        'relation '     => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'prop_city',
            'value' => $city,
            'compare'       => '=',
                'meta_query'    =>  array(
                'relation '  => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'prop_city',
                        'value'     => 'All',
                        'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'prop_type',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare'       => '='
        )
    ),
  );


// $city and $rooms

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_type'     => 'property',
    'meta_query'    =>  array(
        'relation '     => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'prop_city',
            'value' => $city,
            'compare'       => '=',
                'meta_query'    =>  array(
                'relation '  => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'prop_city',
                        'value'     => 'All',
                        'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'prop_rooms',
            'value' => $rooms,
            'compare'       => '='
        ),

    ),
);

// etc
};
```

Comment: Thank you , you mean that I need to make an `args` query for every combination? what should i do if i have 10 or 15 fields?

Comment: I am trying to understand the query you wrote: select 9 posts from `property` cpt where meta value is `propr_city` and value is `$city` till here i get it. now, how the `OR` works? like `else`? let say if the value == All than bring everiything that is not like All?

Comment: Not for every combination. I had a similar problem a while ago (I only had 3 input fields though). I was using `tax_query` and `all` wasn't working. I ended up only checking for `all` on each field and if it wasn't selected, I could fit the queries with `'relation' = > 'AND'`. Definitely not elegant but it got the job done. So you're not checking every `option` on your select, just when it is `all`.